# AWS policy from VPC endpoint to specific ECR repository

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecr, vpc-endpoint

I have a clear problem that I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out.  Let me know if you guys have any suggestions. :)

Thanks in advance!

Scenario:

- Private VPC (no internet access)
- A specific ECR repo name “demo-hello-world”.
- ECS cluster created.
- VPC endpoint created.

Objective:

Need policy example for VPC endpoint to ECR demo-hello-world.

The policy will involve:

- ECR API
- ECR DKR
- **The specific S3 bucket for “demo-hello-world” that ECR uses underneath. <==(I don’t know how to find the ARN for this)**

Thanks!

Gary

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Create s3 gateway endpoint with the arn format.  (I though starport was a user, but I guess it's a special name for ECR.)

arn:aws:s3:::prod-region-starport-layer-bucket/*